# Big side banners

Tags: widgets, css

I would like to have a big header side advertisements like this:
What is the best way to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Register sidebars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) for the banners, then use the text widget to place your code in it. The default widget will strip some HTML code, so you may want to use something less invasive like my [Unfiltered Text Widget](https://gist.github.com/1594985).